# Adding bitmaps to 20 dynamic ImageViews results in java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap

I'm creating 20 ImageViews dynamically and setting bitmap as background. I'm creating the Bitmap from image stored in SDCard.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setId(i);

            imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);            

            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            layout.addView(imageView);

            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = imageView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = 200;
            params.height = 200;
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);            

            // display thbe Bitmap in the ImageView

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathOfImage+i);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bao2);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

I'm getting an **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** error.

Any pointers on how to free up memory or recycle ?

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: images are 1000 * 1000 px. Around 1 MB in size.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 3.0 and above, GC(Garbage Collector) will take care of recycling the bitmap perfectly.

However, if you run your app on older versions, since bitmaps don't get monitored well by the GC, you could get OOM(Out of Memory).

In any case, it's still recommended to call recycle as soon as you are sure you don't need the bitmap anymore. It's good even for new android versions, since it lowers the work needed for automatic memory management.

Here is snippet of recycling bitmap :

```
if (bitmap != null) {
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
}
```

In your case, it would be like below after `imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);`.

```
if (bm != null) {
    bm.recycle();
    bm = null;
}
```

*OOM also depends on type of image loaded(size of image, pixels of image etc).

Answer (score 0):

When you use images too much on your app, it is better to use libraries that will render those images automatically so wont have to worry about memory management. A perfect example would be Picasso. Take a look [Here](http://square.github.io/picasso/).